# How to monitor queries in Elasticsearch?

Tags: elasticsearch, elastic-stack, apm

We are using [Elastic APM](https://www.elastic.co/products/apm) for monitoring our APIs. It shows queries status and useful information about the queries. I want to have the same information about the queries which are sent to Elasticsearch server.

I want to have information about queries, time, status code, etc. Is there any plugin in Elastic stack that I can use for this purpose?

Answer (score 0):

For a high-level overview type of information, have a look at [Elastic Stack Monitoring](https://www.elastic.co/what-is/elasticsearch-monitoring).

If you want to look at any monitoring in more detail, have a look at the [monitoring APIs themselves](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/indices-stats.html).

If you want to log this sort of information, you should set thresholds [for your Elasticsearch slow log](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/index-modules-slowlog.html).

If you want to index and then view data from the slow log, [you can always use Filebeat to ingest that slow log data back into Elasticsearch](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/beats/filebeat/current/filebeat-module-elasticsearch.html).