# How to query most viewed search results in elastic search

Tags: java, spring-boot, elasticsearch, monitoring

Is there any way to query the most viewed search results in a particular elastic search index?
Note that modifying the result scores by calling `function_score` will not work in our case since we do not want to change the result order of other queries.

We are using **Spring Boot** **Elasticsearch** repositories to run the queries and get the results.

Comment: Have you looked at [it](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59466931/6332074)?

Comment: @MuhammadWaqasDilawar Is it possible to query the most viewed results (trending results) just like any other query using elastic monitoring?

Comment: I guess it would be trending query. And [here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/index-modules-slowlog.html#_identifying_search_slow_log_origin) you can find further info.